# Default URL django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

how to configure my site url

MY site URL should be

https://mydomain.com/myapp/  (Default)

in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

in settings.py

```
DEFAULT_HOST = 'https://mydomain.com/myapp/'
```

if i configure the urls like above its returning 404 .

instead of https://mydomain.com/myapp/static/ or https://mydomain.com/myapp/media/

'^' this will remove /myapp/ from my url .

and make it like

https://mydomain.com/static/ or https://mydomain.com/media/

this url contained project is having different wsgi.py,settings.py,urls.py

Comment: Post the whole urls.py. We need more details. And can you please rephrase your question stating what exactly you want, what you have and what's happening that shouldn't happen?

Comment: @Bibhas Done . please look the changes

Comment: `DEFAULT_HOST` doesn't seem like a django settings option. Are you using any 3rd party library?

Comment: just add `myapp/` after the carat (^) in those url patterns to specify a prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    location /myapp {

uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi_myapp.sock; 
  include uwsgi_params;

  uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /myapp;
  uwsgi_modifier1 30;

}
```

i've added the above conf to nginx , i'm using uwsgi. Now the problem is solved .i'm not using any third party . 'DEFAULT_HOST' just see from a search result .